# Spectral power density of thermal noise

Tags: digital-communications, noise, gaussian

In telecommunications the received signal $y(t)$ of a receiver is equal to $x(t)S+n(t)$ where $x(t)$ is the sent signal of the sender , $S$ is a constant which describes the total attenuation of the sender receiver channel and $n(t)$ is the noise.Assume that $n(t)$ is purely thermal it will follow as a consequence of that Gauss's normal distribution.Which will be the spectral power density of such noise?

Comment: Sorry, this feels a little disconnected. The distribution has nothing to do with the power spectral density (PSD). Gaussian noise cam be white, pink, brown or have all different types of spectra. The PSD of the noise depends on the mechanism that creates the noise. There are many different types of thermal noise but if you are referring to Johnson–Nyquist noise, that's mostly white so in this case the PSD of the noise would be flat.

Answer (score 2):

“Thermal noise” is synonymous with “[Johnson-Nyquist noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise)”, “Johnson noise”, or “Nyquist noise”: they all refer to the same noise process and is well approximated as a Additive Gaussian White Noise process within any practical bandwidth we would use through the audio, RF and microwave spectrum. This is in contrast to other noise sources such as 1/f noise. The total power dissipated in a matched load due to thermal noise in any given bandwidth is given by $kTB$ where $k$ is Boltzmann's Constant, $T$ is the temperature in degrees Kelvin and $B$ is the bandwidth in Hz.  Since the noise is "white" it will be uniformly distributed across that given bandwidth and thus $kT$ is the noise density in watts/Hz. At room temperature (300°K) this is approximately -174 dBm/Hz as a power spectral density.

Comment: There's a factor of 4 that you need to worry about, Dan.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson the factor 4 is in the noisy source. Since only half of the voltage drops across the load resistor when matched for maximum power transfer, the power dissipated in the load has no factor of 4, and I believe the power in the load is just kTB; I will update to be more clear that it is the power in a matched load

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise#/media/File:JohnsonNoiseEquivalentCircuits.svg

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Scroll down to the section in that same article "Noise Voltage and Power" "Since only half of the source voltage drops across any one of these resistors, the resulting noise power is given by $P=k_bT\Delta F$ where P is the thermal noise power in watts. Notice that this is independent of the noise-generating resistance. " en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise